# Login Activity not going to next screen

Tags: android, sqlite

When I press Login Button it shows (Username/Password Wrong) even if i put the right Username & password. It doesn't go to next Activity. the Sign up activity is working fine.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button signup;
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bsignup);

    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent button = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SignUp.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(button);
        }
    });
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.BLogin) {

        EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFusername);
        String str = a.getText().toString();
        EditText b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpassword);
        String pass = b.getText().toString();

        String password = helper.searchPass(str);
        if (password.equals(pass)) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Display.class);
            i.putExtra("Username", str);
            startActivity(i);

        }else{

            Toast temp = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username/Password Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            temp.show();

        }
    }
}}
```

SignupActivity

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
}

public void onSignUpClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()== R.id.Bsignupbutton){
        EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFname);
        EditText uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFuname);
        EditText phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFphone);
        EditText pass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpass1);
        EditText pass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFpass2);

        String namestr = name.getText().toString();
        String unamestr = uname.getText().toString();
        String phonestr = phone.getText().toString();
        String pass1str = pass1.getText().toString();
        String pass2str = pass2.getText().toString();

        if (!pass1str.equals(pass2str)){
            Toast pass = Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Password doesn't match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            pass.show();
        }else{

            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.setName(namestr);
            c.setUname(unamestr);
            c.setPhone(phonestr);
            c.setPass(pass1str);

            helper.insertContact(c);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    }
}}
```

DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_UNAME = "uname";
private static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS = "pass";
SQLiteDatabase db;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id integer primary key not null , " +
        "name text not null , uname text not null , phone text not null, pass text not null);";
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;
}
public void insertContact(Contact c) {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_UNAME, c.getUname());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, c.getPhone());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getPass());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME , null  , values);

}

public String searchPass(String uname)
{
    db= this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select uname, pass from "+TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if (a.equals(uname))
            {

                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);
}}
```

Comment: 1) `v.getId() == R.id.BLogin` ... Is this working? 2) What about `password.equals(pass)`? Have you made this work without a database?

Comment: It's working now. after i update the android studio it was working all ok. it was the gradle problem.
Thanks a lot brother

Comment: If it was a Gradle problem, your code would have never run on any device. Android Studio also had no control over your Java code logic

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the calling of the method `public void onButtonClick(View v) { }` try to check it. Is it working or not?

Comment: It's working now. after i update the android studio it was working all ok. it was the gradle problem.
Thanks a lot brother